# How to verify if a public key matched private key signature?

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa

How does one verify that a public key matched private key?

On start of the application, 2048-bit RSA keys are loaded from base64 PEM encoded string. I wish to verify that the keys are valid and that they match before continuing. The signing and verification is done by the underlining library I'm using.

I could sign and verify dummy data, but I am looking for alternative solutions.

Starter playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tsB8Yp-xs47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple

```
func verifyKeyPair(private, public string) bool {
    // Handle errors here
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(rsaPrivateKey))
    key, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    pubBlock, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(rsaPublicKey))
    pubKey, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pubBlock.Bytes)
    return key.PublicKey.Equal(pubKey)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tR6Ns0wDrlN

Answer (score 1):

or alternatively if you want to handle other supported algorithms :

```
// KeysMatch generic check if public key is the same.
func KeysMatch(priv crypto.PrivateKey, pub crypto.PublicKey) bool {

    privkey, ok := priv.(interface {
        Public() crypto.PublicKey
    })

    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    pubkey, ok := privkey.Public().(interface {
        Equal(crypto.PublicKey) bool
    })

    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    return pubkey.Equal(pub)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm guessing that @Community is suggesting you add this section to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860539/9731176